# PHP exec() and SSL

Tags: php, ssl, exec

I use third part framework (exe file) for conneting one php application with taxt service.

Framework is open source, exe file sign xml, give soap cover and send it to central information tax system.

When i open this in batch file (run.bat), all working good:
Raverus.FiskalizacijaDEV.EXE.exe GetInvoice "" "C:\xampp\htdocs\get\racun.xml" "C:\xampp\htdocs\get\OutInvoice.xml" true true "C:\xampp\htdocs\get\certifikat.pfx" "Pwd"

but when i open in PHP using "echo exec('run.bat');" server give me this error:
The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

Does anybody have idea how i can resolve this? When i mannualy open batch file (in windows) all working. I use Xampp server.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP user doesn't have the needed configuration or access rights.

If you are unsure which user is running your PHP script, you can use something like this to find out:

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
system('set', $retval);
echo ' </pre>';
```

it should give out information as to which user your PHP is using. Then set up the env *for that user* so he can run your batch file. This might include importing the certificate for that user.